# Need help calculating integral $\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+4)^2}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need some help calculating the integral

$\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+4)^2}$

I tried integration by parts, but I could not arrive to an answer.

Comment: The Maple 17 code $$with(Student[Calculus1]):
IntTutor(1/(x^2+1)^2, x);
 $$ produces [the solution](http://rapidshare.com/files/1369331689/IntTutor.pdf) step by step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try letting $x=2\tan t$. Then $x^2+4=4(1+\tan^2 t)=4\sec^2 t$, $dx=2\sec^2 tdt$.

Comment: With this substitution I came to the result $\frac{t}{16} + \frac{\sin{2t}}{32} + C$. I am having difficulty in finding $\sin{2t}$ when $t$ is substituted with $\arctan{\frac{x}{2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, note that

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2} = -\frac{1}{2 a} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2} = -\frac{1}{2 a} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\arctan{(x/a)}}{a}$$

Carry out the differentiation and substitute $a=2$; I get

$$\frac18 \frac{x}{x^2+4} + \frac{1}{16} \arctan{\frac{x}{2}}+C$$

Comment: This is pretty awesome, never thought of obtaining primitives through partial differentiation.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: this is a pretty common trick, although easily misused.